# JavaScript Chainable Method Delimma

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, method-chaining

I have 2 methods that I'd like to use as chainable methods. Other methods may be chained to further modify text.

**left** returns X characters from the left.
**right** returns X characters from the right.

Currently I can do this:

```js
var txt = "hello";
S$(txt).left(4).right(2).val //returns "ll"
```

What I want to do is this.
Basically I want to return the results after the last chained method without having to call the property. Is this possible?

```js
var txt = "hello";
S$(txt).left(4).right(2) //returns "ll"
```

Below is the main code:

```js
(function (global) {
    
    var jInit = function(text){
        this.text = text;
        this.val = text;
    }
    
    var jIn = function(text){
        return new jInit(text);
    }
    
    var jStringy = jStringy || jIn;
    
    
    jInit.prototype.left = function (num_char) {
        if (num_char == undefined) {
            throw "Number of characters is required!";
        }
        this.val = this.val.substring(0, num_char);
        return this;
    }
    
    jInit.prototype.right = function (numchar) {
        this.val = this.val.substring(this.val.length - numchar, this.val.length);
        return this;
    }

    global.jStringy = global.S$ = jStringy;
    
    return this;

}(window));
```

Comment: I assume left and right will always operate on strings?  You might be able to extend the javascript string object with those properties and get the value without having to call val.

Comment: You want your chainable function to return a `String` object but you don't want to explicitly tell WHEN the chain has ended right? Then the only way would be to create `left` and `right` functions in `String.prototype`.

Comment: That's what I feared, But since this is a library doing prototypes isn't going to be professional.

Comment: For example, `lodash` is a very professional library and they have chainable functions. It uses `.value()` to end chains. So you can do it too, it's not too verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *override* `valueOf` and `toString` methods of `Object` to archieve it.

Example:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 5,
    valueOf: function(){
        return this.value;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return 'value of this object is' + this.value;
    }
};
```

As Javascript is a [duck typing language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), nothing will prevent you from performing **mathematical operations** and **string concatenation** against *primitive values/objects* as these methods are called during expression evaluation process no matter where they came from.

Examples:

`console.log(myObject + 10);`
 will print 15

`alert(myObject);`
 will print 'value of this object is 5'

Comment: Thank You! This is so far the best it gets.
Why doesn't it work for?
console.log(S$("hello").left(4).right(2))
console.log(myObject)

Comment: @ChicagoExcelUser - `console.log()` does not coerce a `.toString()` conversion on its own - it will happily just print out the contents of an object.